# Cannot Subscript a value of type CNLabeledValue<CNSocialProfiles> with an index of type CNLabeledValue<CNSocialProfiles>

Tags: swift, xcode, indexof, facebook-social-plugins, subscript

In the new contacts framework, I am trying to add social profiles and I am using a line of code that works in other projects, but for some reason it just does not work in the particular one that I am working in. Here is the code below

```
let twitterProfile = CNLabeledValue(label: "Twitter", value:
CNSocialProfile(urlString: nil, username: "ios_blog",
userIdentifier: nil, service: CNSocialProfileServiceTwitter))

contactData.socialProfiles = [twitterProfile]
```

I keep getting this error message: "`Cannot Subscript a value of type CNLabeledValue<CNSocialProfile> with an index of type CNLabeledValue<CNSocialProfile>.`"

If I put it in another project it works, but I would need it to work in mine and for some reason I just keep getting this error.

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Which line exactly is giving you the issue? It doesn't look like you're trying to subscript anything in this code. Can you include the definition of `contactData`?

Comment: let contactData = CNMutableContact()

Comment: let contactData = CNMutableContact()        I'm not doing anything wrong in terms of that, and If I try to save the phoneNumber, name etd. That is working, I am only having the issue with the socialProfiles. I think some other parts of the code might cause this, but I have no idea what. Thank you!-  @Dave Weston

Comment: As I understand it, that error is coming from the compiler, correct? Which line exactly is it complaining about? Can you try commenting out the line where you assign to the `socialProfiles` property and see if the error message goes away or changes at all?

Comment: It is not the compiler, I am unable to even run the code, it recognizes the error before I run it. I have no idea which part of the code should I share since this I never saw an error like this before. Thank You guys, let me know what you think. @Dave Weston

Answer (score 1):

Your problem cannot be reproduced as described. This code compiles and runs just fine:

```
let contactData = CNMutableContact()
let twitterProfile = CNLabeledValue(label: "Twitter", value: CNSocialProfile(urlString: nil, username: "ios_blog", userIdentifier: nil, service: CNSocialProfileServiceTwitter))
contactData.socialProfiles = [twitterProfile]
```

It is all very well to say that this problem is caused by other code, and that may be true, but you didn't *show* us any other code. The code you did show us, works.

Comment: Actually I suspect that the line the compiler is complaining about is some other line entirely. I can't see anything about the code you supplied that would elicit any mention of indexing.

Comment: It is not the compiler, I am unable to even run the code, it recognizes the error before I run it. I have no idea which part of the code should I share since this I never saw an error like this before. Thank You guys, let me know what you think. @matt

Comment: I actually solved that issue, and I do not use getters anymore, however I ran into another issue, this issue happens when I try adding the social profiles and I get this SIGABRT error

Comment: 2017-01-23 00:10:11.323693 FVSCANNER[765:154249] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles

2017-01-23 00:10:11.325124 FVSCANNER[765:154249] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.

Could not cast value of type 'FVSCANNER.starter' (0x1001f4d80) to 'UINavigationController' (0x1a8cf8748).

2017-01-23 00:10:15.276951 FVSCANNER[765:154249] Could not cast value of type 'FVSCANNER.starter' (0x1001f4d80) to 'UINavigationController' (0x1a8cf8748).

(lldb)

Comment: You should add an answer describing the reason for the original issue and what you did to fix it. Then you should create a new question for the SIGABRT error.

Comment: Hey, I did what you asked, could you please refer to this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41799682/contacts-framework-social-profiles-sigabrt-error-in-swift @DaveWeston

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, that in the method I was getting an error was a getter and that is why it didn't work. 
In order to fix it, you need to use a function.